# BindingSource.Find Multiple Columns

Tags: c#, winforms, find, bindingsource, multiple-columns

Is it possible to use the Find method of a BindingSource on multiple columns?

For example, say I have a gridview displaying current pets; two comboboxes, cboPetType and cboGender; and a button to create a new record into the Pet table based on the values of these two comboboxes.

Now, let's say I only want one of each PetType/Gender combination (Dog - M, Cat - F, etc.).  So, if I have a Dog - M pet in my BindingSource and a user selects Dog and M from the comboboxes, I would like to stop the user to inform them that combination already exists.

In the past, I have used the BindingSource.Find method to do something similar, but, as far as I can tell, that is only good for searching one column (i.e. BindingSource.Find("PetType", cboPetType.SelectedValue);).

Is it possible to search a bindingsource based on multiple columns?  If not, any suggestions to achieve my desired result?  Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately this isn't possible. While it's likely that given a *particular* data source that such a search would be fairly simple, doing it in a more generic way (as the `BindingSource` would) is a little less transparent. For one, the syntax would be less than obvious. Here's a somewhat contrived solution:

```
public class Key
{
    public string PropertyName {get; set;}
    public object Value {get; set;}
}

public static int Find(this BindingSource source, params Key[] keys)
{
    PropertyDescriptor[] properties = new PropertyDescriptor[keys.Length];

    ITypedList typedList = source as ITypedList;

    if(source.Count <= 0) return -1;

    PropertyDescriptorCollection props;

    if(typedList != null) // obtain the PropertyDescriptors from the list
    {
        props = typedList.GetItemProperties(null);
    }
    else // use the TypeDescriptor on the first element of the list
    {
        props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(source[0]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
    {
        properties[i] = props.Find(keys[i].PropertyName, true, true); // will throw if the property isn't found
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
    { 
        object row = source[i];
        bool match = true;

        for(int p = 0; p < keys.Count; p++)
        {
            if(properties[p].GetValue(row) != keys[p].Value))
            {
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(match) return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
BindingSource source = // your BindingSource, obviously 

int index = source.Find(
    new Key { PropertyName = "PetType", Value = "Dog" },
    new Key { PropertyName = "Gender", Value = "M" });
```

Bear in mind that for this to be usable, you *really* need a smarter comparison algorithm, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader. Checking for an implementation of `IComparable` would be a good start. Nonetheless, the concept should carry through regardless of that particular point of implementation.

Note that this won't take advantage of any of the possible performance optimizations that might be implemented by the underlying data source, whereas the single column `Find` would.

Comment: Pefect. Only correction is that this line if(properties[p].GetValue(row) != keys[p].Value)) has an extra ')' that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Another simpler solution, in case someone runs into the same issue. This works when the BindingSource is a DataView:

```
MyBindingSource.Sort = "Column1,Column2"
Dim underlyingView As DataView = DirectCast(MyBindingSource.List, DataView)
Dim searchVals As New List(Of Object)
searchVals.Add("SearchString1")
searchVals.Add("SearchString2")

Dim ListIndex as Integer = underlyingView.Find(searchVals.ToArray)

If ListIndex >=0 Then
    MyBindingList.Position = ListIndex
Else
    'No matches, so what you need to do...
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my version based on the above examples. It works very well.

```
Public Class clsBSHelpers

    Public Structure Key

        Public PropertyName As String
        Public Value As Object

        Sub New(ByVal pPropertyName As String, ByVal pValue As Object)
            PropertyName = pPropertyName
            Value = pValue
        End Sub

    End Structure

    Public Shared Function Find(ByVal Source As BindingSource, ByVal ParamArray keys As Key()) As Boolean

        Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder
        For i As Integer = 0 To keys.Length - 1
            If sb.Length > 0 Then
                sb.Append(",")
            End If
            sb.Append(keys(i).PropertyName)
        Next

        Source.Sort = sb.ToString
        Dim underlyingView As DataView = DirectCast(Source.List, DataView)
        Dim searchVals As New List(Of Object)
        For i As Integer = 0 To keys.Length - 1
            searchVals.Add(keys(i).Value)
        Next

        Dim ListIndex As Integer = underlyingView.Find(searchVals.ToArray)

        If ListIndex >= 0 Then
            Source.Position = ListIndex
            Find = True
        Else
            Find = False
            'No matches, so what you need to do...
        End If

        Return Find

    End Function

End Class
```

I call it thus:

```
e.Cancel = clsBSHelpers.Find(CastingBedBindingSource, _
                             New clsBSHelpers.Key("PlantID", m_PlantID), _
                             New clsBSHelpers.Key("LineBedNUmber", m_LineBedNumber))
```

Hope this helps those that like it simple.

Answer (score 0):

The more simple solution is by using Extension Method:

```
var id1 = "id1";
var id2 = "id2";

var data = bindingSource1.Cast<DataModelType>().Single(r => r.ID1 == id1 && r.ID2 == id2);
bindingSource1.Position = bindingSource1.IndexOf(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sorcobj = SorcBs.Current as Data.Student;

if (sorcobj == null) return;

TrgtBs.Position = TrgtBs.List.IndexOf(TrgtBs.List.OfType<Data.Student>().FirstOrDefault(s => s.NAME == sorc.NAME));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to help the users to understand why do you think your answer solves the issue. Thank you.